# collectd disk aggregation does not work?

Tags: collectd

The following aggregates all the CPUs in one specific host, creating `cpu-all-sum/cpu-idle`, `cpu-all-sum/cpu-nice`, etc.

```
<Aggregation>
    Plugin "cpu"
    Type "cpu"
    SetPlugin "cpu"
    SetPluginInstance "all-%{aggregation}"
    GroupBy "Host"
    GroupBy "TypeInstance"
    CalculateSum true
</Aggregation>
```

However, the following does not work:

```
<Aggregation>
    Plugin "disk"
    PluginInstance "/xvd./"
    Type "disk"
    SetPlugin "disk"
    SetPluginInstance "all-%{aggregation}"
    GroupBy "Host"
    GroupBy "TypeInstance"
    CalculateSum true
</Aggregation>
```

... it is supposed to aggregate IO ops on all the "xvd" disks. It creates no files, and there's nothing in the log.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what collectd logs for me in a similar situation with `debug` log level:

```
aggregation plugin: The "disk_octets" type (data set) has more than one data source. This is currently not supported by this plugin. Sorry.
```

I'm not quite sure, but it seems that the aggregation plugin does not support plugins with mutliple value samples - `cpu` only has one value, and `disk` has 2 - read and write.